# In ASP.NET MVC, how do I serve pure static content?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I configure ASP.NET (or ASP.NET MVC more specifically) to treat certain folders as purely 'static', i.e. content of those folders should not pass through methods in Global.asax like Application_BeginRequest and Application_PostAuthenticateRequest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this was possible (and the case) with IIS 6.0 or IIS 7.0+ (classic mode), it is no longer possible when you run your application in IIS 7.0+ integrated pipeline mode. It is the very basic idea of this integrated mode. Everything gets served through ASP.NET, even the static files. In fact to be more precise ASP.NET doesn't serve those static files. It simply delegates this to IIS. But since you are in in integrated mode all requests go through it. It is normally not something that you should worry about.